# Amazon RDS : ER_RECORD_FILE_FULL: The table is full occured while creating temporary table in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-rds, temp-tables

I have hosted my database on Amazon RDS. It is *db.r3.xlarge* instance and having 60Gb magnetic storage (40gb free). Recently I have written one stored procedure which gets user input as *MEDIUMTEXT* comma separated string, parsed it and insert values into temporary table. Here is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ntadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
    IN  cStr      MEDIUMTEXT,   -- 16777215  --LONGTEXT 4294967295
)   DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_phone;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_phone (phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(" INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_phone(phone) VALUES ", cStr);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

and this stored procedure call like this

```
CALL sp_test("'1234','4567','897458','5784585','453434'");
Note: parameter (cStr) may be come vary vary long string.
```

It's working fine on my development instance and also fine in major case on production instance. but some this it's through error "ER_RECORD_FILE_FULL: The table 'tmp_phone' is full.

As I mentioned earlier, I have 40gb of free space. 
I have set *VARIABLES* in *parameter group* is as follows :

```
innodb_file_per_table = ON 
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
max_heap_table_size   = 128000
tmp_table_size        = 128000
```

Should I have to increase *max_heap_table_size* because my maximum possible value should come 16mb in size.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the SQL you are generating:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_phone(phone)
    VALUES '1234','4567','897458','5784585','453434'
```

Now look at the correct syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_phone(phone)
    VALUES ('1234'),('4567'),('897458'),('5784585'),('453434')
```

Next look at the space requirements...  `max_heap_table_size` limits the size of any subsequently `CREATEd` `MEMORY` table.  The 128K will limit you to only a few thousand rows.  It sounds from `MEDIUMTEXT` that you may need a lot more.

It is reasonable to set `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` (which is not relevent here) to about 1% of RAM (300M in your case); certainly 16M of `MEDIUMTEXT` (or a bit more for overhead).